# Cython compiler error

Tags: python, compiler-errors, cython

I haven't been able to find much about this, but when attempting to compile one of my python scripts with cython, it gives me this error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
import traceback #line:24
import bcrypt #line:25
Y =str (os .path .dirname (os .path .abspath (__file__ )))#line:28
IH =open #line:29
IA =str #line:30
IK =print #line:31
   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

headlessobfu.pyx:29:4: Expected an identifier or literal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    ext_modules = cythonize("headlessobfu.pyx")
  File "C:\Users\justi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1026, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "C:\Users\justi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1146, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: headlessobfu.pyx
```

I haven't been able to find the exact cause of this error. I was able to get simple scripts to compile just fine. The python runs just fine on it's own. Is it a problem with my python formatting?

Here is the command line argument I am running:

```
py setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

If anyone has a solution please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please paste a Cython file as small as possible that does not compile?

Comment: Just the smallest file I can get to not compile?

Comment: Ok so through testing I can see that it occurs when the compiler detects "Invalid python" I will check for bad formatting in my code

Comment: Is this a Python 2/3 issue? Cython defaults to reading code as Python 2 I think

Comment: It could be as this is in python 3.6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default Cython assumes Python 2 syntax, even when you're using Python 3 (edit 2021: Cython 3 will change this and largely assume Python 3 syntax by default). Here's the minimum, complete example you should have created:

cy_print_test.pyx

```
x = print
```

---

If I compile it with Cython

```
cython cy_print_test.pyx
```

I get the error message that you do. `print` is not an identifier or literal because under Python 2 syntax it is a special statement.

However, if I compile it with Cython set to use Python 3 syntax:

```
cython -3 cy_print_test.pyx
```

it works fine - under Python 3 syntax print is a function and so this makes perfect sense.

---

Alternative ways of getting Python 3 syntax would be to add the following line to the start of your .pyx file

```
#cython: language_level=3
```

or to specify it as a compiler directive in `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize('cy_print_test.pyx', compiler_directives={'language_level': 3}),
)
```

(note that your `setup.py` should also form part of the minimum, complete example in your question)

Comment: I fixed it by de-obfuscating the code, but this answer works as well. This would be a much cleaner solution that what I did.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this has to do with cython and python formatting. The code has to be totally obfuscated and with no errors or the compiler won't work. So work through the compiler and fix each error as it arises. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

we need to **install the required dependencies**, and I guess you are **missing out the python3-dev.**
Try these commands on terminal (cmd)

```
$ pip3 install cython
$ sudo apt install update
$ sudo apt install build-essential
$ sudo apt install python3-dev
```

then run the `$ python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace` again. it should work.

Comment: I don't think this has much to do with the question (if they were missing the -dev package then they'd get errors at the C compiling stage)