# Problems installing library pyknotid

Tags: python, cython, python-wheel

I'm a (very) new Python user. The reason I'm learning Python now (I normally use R) is that supposedly there's a useful knot theory package called [pyknotid](https://pyknotid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I succeeded in installing many other packages, but this one is causing me real trouble, and I've already worked my way around a dozen or so error messages. Currently I'm terminally stuck at the following error messages:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyknotid
ERROR: Failed building wheel for planarity
Failed to build pyknotid planarity
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyknotid, planarity, which is required to 
install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I'm aware that this package hasn't been updated since 2018, and it seems like it never had many users. But some of its functions would be immensely useful for a research project I am working on. I've been banging my head at this for many hours with no success.

I was wondering if anyone could be as kind as to see if they can install this package, and if so, figure out what steps I am currently missing. Even just knowing that someone *can* succeed in installing and loading the package would give me motivation to keep hacking at it. Let me know if I can provide any further details.

Thank you very much in advance.

I have already tried:

```
pip install pyknotid
```

Which produces the above error messages.

Some of the package functions require Cython so I have also installed that succesfully.

I am using Visual Studio Code and running Python 3.11.5.

I also tried installing older Python versions (on another PC; v. 2.7 and 3.5), but ran into altogether different error messages and also failed to install the pyknotid package.

Comment: can you please add the entire error trace? there is likely a more specific error message present higher up in the trace.

Comment: I would aslo advice to try a version between 3.11 and 2.7, maybe 3.8

Comment: Hi, thanks. I will try that.

I can't post the entire error trace, since it's too long. But the errors start with:

      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
     
          def embed_drawplanar(self):
              status = cplanarity.gp_AttachDrawPlanar(self.theGraph)
              if status == cplanarity.NOTOK:
                  raise RuntimeError("planarity: failed attaching drawplanar.")
              status = cplanarity.gp_Embed(self.theGraph,
                                 ^

Comment: Is this what you are experiencing? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51722323/cython-compiler-error

Comment: Only the first line is the same, so I don't think so, and the proposed solutions linked didn't work. Installing on Python 3.7 didn't work either, unfortunately (got the same error messages). Would like to hear if anyone is able to install pyknotid.

Here's something else that is happening:

Comment: Here's something else that is happening:

 LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'm.lib'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.37.32822\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1181

Comment: @robster [edit] your post and [put those details in it](/help/how-to-ask). Don't put them in comments.